# How assert parameter name without value using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have a soapui response which contains several parameters sometime the parameter name is repeated and contains different value.
How can we assert the existence of parameters?
i can assert timestamp, data, profile,full,id,endpoints because they are unique but label,branches, url, api-version, appname are repeated several times.

I know how to assert the value of a parameter but i do not know how to assert only the paramter name like label,branches, url, api-version, appname.

response:

```
<response>{
  "timestamp": "2016-04-14T17:53:29Z",
  "data": {
    "profile": {
      "full": "test"
    },
    "id": "544cc493-8f4a-4f14-b95b-2c127f54caac",
    "endpoints": [
      {
        "label": "Gify",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/gify/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify"
      },
      {
        "label": "x1",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/x1/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify2"
      },
      {
        "label": "y1",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/y1/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ]}
        <response>
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? You should be able to collect the distinct values and check you have the same number of them as keys

Comment: i tried but def endpoint = context.expand( '${login#Endpoint}' )
def response = context.expand( '${login#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://au.io/ns/201\'; //ns1:login_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )
def label1 endpoint.label[0] = ("label")

assert endpoint.contains(label1)

Comment: Can you put that in the question? Code is impossible to read in comments

Comment: @TemplogLog, you know already that how to find a value of a property like you mentioned url, name, label etc. If you get the value of the respective property means that the property is part of the response. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I really understand the situation, it seems that you're receiving a *XML* response which has a *JSON* in a node attribute... isn't it?

Despite this what I understand is basically that you want to check that all `endpoints` entries in your *JSON* contains all mandatory attributes: `label`, `branch`, `appname`; and all `branches` in each endpoint contains  `url`, `name`, `api_version` and `label`.

So a possible approach is to use [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and check if the element is not `null`. Something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonTxt = '''{
      "timestamp": "2016-04-14T17:53:29Z",
      "id": "544cc493-8f4a-4f14-b95b-2c127f54caac",
      "endpoints": [
      {
        "label": "Gify",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/gify/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify"
      },
      {
        "label": "x1",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/x1/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify2"
      }
   ]
}'''
// parse json
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonTxt)
// for each endpoint
json.endpoints.each { endpoint ->
    // check that label is not null
    assert endpoint.label != null, 'ENDPOINT ENTRY NOT CONTAINS LABEL'
    // check that appname is not null
    assert endpoint.appname != null, 'ENDPOINT ENTRY NOT CONTAINS APPNAME'
    // ...
    assert endpoint.branches != null, 'ENDPOINT ENTRY NOT CONTAINS BRACHES' 
    // for each branch
    assert endpoint.branches.each { branch ->
        // and so on...
        assert branch.url != null, 'BRANCH ENTRY NOT CONTAINS URL'
        assert branch.name != null, 'BRANCH ENTRY NOT CONTAINS NAME'
        assert branch.api_version != null, 'BRANCH ENTRY NOT CONTAINS API_VERSION'
        assert branch.label != null, 'BRANCH ENTRY NOT CONTAINS LABEL'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Unlikely *XML* and *XSD*, there is no schema to validate against your *Json*, however you can create a *template* to validate your response against using `JsonSlurper`. Since you only want to check for the `name`s of the elements not its values you can create a function to compare the `name`s recursively:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// compare json against the "schema"
def compareJsonNames(json,schema) {

    if(json instanceof Map){ 
        // it's a map... check all names
        assert(json.keySet() == schema.keySet())

        // for every element in a map...
        json.eachWithIndex { it,index ->
            def key = schema.keySet().getAt(index)
            return compareJsonNames(it.value, schema.find{ e -> e.key == key}.value)
        }

    }else if(json instanceof List){ 
        // it's a list, compare its elements
        json.eachWithIndex { it, index ->
            return compareJsonNames(it,schema[index])
        }
    }

    // it's a simple value nothing to do
}

def jsonTxt = '''{
      "timestamp": "2016-04-14T17:53:29Z",
      "id": "544cc493-8f4a-4f14-b95b-2c127f54caac",
      "endpoints": [
      {
        "label": "Gify",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/gify/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify"
      },
      {
        "label": "x1",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "/x1/v1.0/",
            "name": "test",
            "api_version": "1.0",
            "label": "test"
          }
        ],
        "appname": "gify2"
      }
   ]
}'''

// template to validate the names
def template = '''{
        "label": "",
        "branches": [
          {
            "url": "",
            "name": "",
            "api_version": "",
            "label": ""
          }
        ],
        "appname": ""
}'''

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()

// parse your response and the expected template
def json = slurper.parseText(jsonTxt)
def jsonTemplate = slurper.parseText(template) 
// check if each endpoint are well formed against the template
json.endpoints.each {
    compareJsonNames(it,jsonTemplate)
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Nice, one comment though. For eg: user get the error message as expected when `appname` it self is missing. However, it is giving the same assertion error when value of `appname` is empty say `"appname": ""` which may not be expected, i guess.

Comment: @Rao ouch... you're right! `:)`... I want to avoid `null` to comparison but I don't take in account that empty string is false. I update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad, and you are so quick. :)

Comment: Maybe i did not explain very well my problem, what i wanted is to validate all parameter name, for example we have "label", if after a code modification the label name now is "_label" or it's missing i want to detect the modification.

Comment: @TemplogLog but the code I put in the answers does this. If for example there is no element with `'label'` as name then the `assert` not pass. maybe I don't understand well your comment.

Comment: @TemplogLog or your `json` has a specific structure and you want to catch what is exactly the change and not only that some element is missing?

Comment: yes i want to catch the change in the name of the parameter like label for example